# Class Factory Method with Multiple Parameters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I am practicing my Objective C skills and have come across a small issue, although I can't seem to find a straight answer to this issue anywhere I look. In the Apple developer guides I am reading, there is nothing in there telling me how to use a class factory method with multiple parameters (say 3 parameters) and return the initialized object via the overridden init method.

Here I have a simple class called XYZPerson.

```
@implementation XYZPerson

// Class Factory Method
+ (id)person:(NSString *)firstName with:(NSString *)lastName andWith:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth {
    // need to return [ [self alloc] init with the 3 paramaters]; here
    // Or some other way to do so..
}

// Overridden init method
- (id)init:(NSString *)firstName with:(NSString *)lastName andWIth:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
        _dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    return self;
}

// Use the initialized instance variables in a greeting
- (void)sayHello {
    NSLog(@"Hello %@ %@", self.firstName, self.lastName);
}
```

And then in my main I am instantiating an XYZPerson object

```
XYZPerson *person = [XYZPerson person:@"John" with:@"Doe" andWith:[NSDate date]];
[person sayHello];
```

Can anybody give me a small pointer on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want the following:

```
+ (id)person:(NSString *)firstName with:(NSString *)lastName andWith:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth {
    XYZPerson *result = [[self alloc] init:firstName with:lastName andWith:dateOfBirth];

    return result;
}
```

If you aren't using ARC, add an `autorelease` to the `return`.

BTW - change the return type of the `init` method to `instancetype` instead of `id`.

Comment: You can also go ahead and change the return type of the above method to `instancetype`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation XYZPerson

// Class Factory Method
+ (instanceType ) person:(NSString *)firstName with:(NSString *)lastName andWith:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth {

return [[[self class] alloc]init: firstName with: lastName andWith:dateOfBirth];

}

- (instanceType ) init:(NSString *)firstName with:(NSString *)lastName andWIth:(NSDate *)dateOfBirth {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _firstName = [firstName copy];
        _lastName = [lastName copy];
        _dateOfBirth = [dateOfBirth copy];
//nb added copy to each of these, we do not own these objects, they could be lost to us..

///  or you could do this instead..
//assuming you synthesised getters/setters for (strong) properties..

[self setFirstName:firstName];
[self setLastName:lastName];
[self setDateOfBirth: dateOfBirth];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe [self class] is appropriate here - it might work, but its unnecessary.  self is not an instance of XYZperson in a class (+) method.